# How do i access my api after hosting in nuxt

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, nuxt.js, vercel

I will like my baseUrl to be my domain name instead of localhost. Something like https://domain/api/post/allpost. I developed with nuxt and deployed with zeit now. But when i try to access the api using mydomain/api/post/all, it fails. But it works only in localhost:3000/api. I use axios.

**in nuxt.config.js**

```
...
env: {
    baseUrl: process.env.baseUrl || "http://localhost:3000"
  }
```

**in nuxt page**

```
Axios.get(`${process.env.baseUrl}/api/post/all`)
```

even when i change the baseUrl from localhost to "https://my-domain.com", It still cannot call my api routes. Please i need help

Comment: What do you mean `it still can't call`? What's the error? We need more info.

Comment: failed to load localhost:3000/api/post

Comment: Are you using the axios module? https://axios.nuxtjs.org/

Comment: no, i imported axios from node_module